# Need to make changes in API for created by and updated by column

Tags: database, spring-boot, model, userdetailsservice

In the existing spring boot API the created by and updated by field is getting saved by generating a random id but now I should get the username instead of random id by which user it is updated what changes should  be done in the API or their is need to create a new API to save the details.

In the created by and updated by field it should display by which user it is modified it should display the username and also get saved in database.